# How do I add  to my VARCHAR field via Python

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to add a special character (, codepoint U+1F352) to a VARCHAR field in a MySQL database and it's just giving me the empty string in the database.

```
sql = "UPDATE table SET special_char = %s WHERE id = %s"
sql_db.execute(sql, (special_char, id))
```

I have # coding=utf-8 at the top of the page. The character I'm adding is one of these: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji#endnote_U2600_as_of_Unicode_version

Comment: Maybe a database client is not smart enough to display it?

Comment: please add the special char as it is in your code (`special_char=u'\xb0'` or something like that)

Comment: I works ok when I type it in directly to the database. Just not when I do it via Python.

Comment: The code is 1F352 according to http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1F300.pdf however, "print u'1F352'" prints 352

Comment: You'd use `u'\U0001F352'`. What version of MySQL is this? All but the most recent versions do *not* support unicode outside of the BMP.

Comment: I tried with u'\U0001F352' which printed perfected but no joy. MySQL is Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.29. Some strings I downloaded via the Facebook API contain this character and they insert perfectly as well. However, I double checked and I can't manually enter it.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is compatible with Unicode Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP) (characters u'00000000'– u'0000FFFF).

The reference for the special character you are trying to use is u'0001F352'. Note there are 5 non-zero digits at the end so this isn't BMP.

Luckily, if you are looking for coloured symbols there are a few in BMP.

Some appear automatically as coloured such as the star: u'00002B50'. Others, you need to activate the colours by putting '\U0000FE0F' at the end, for example, u'\U00002666' and u'\U00002666\U0000FE0F'

Others include:
u'\U000021AA\U0000FE0F'
u'\U00002668\U0000FE0F'
u'\U000023EC\U0000FE0F'
u'\U00002757\U0000FE0F'
u'\U00002665\U0000FE0F'
u'\U00002660\U0000FE0F'
u'\U00002666\U0000FE0F'
u'\U00002663\U0000FE0F'
u'\U000026AA\U0000FE0F'
u'\U000026AB\U0000FE0F'
u'\U00002B50\U0000FE0F'
u'\U0000261D\U0000FE0F'

For more check out the unified characters in this database. http://www.unicode.org/~scherer/emoji4unicode/snapshot/utc.html.